# I keep getting an syntax error with roslib.load_manifest (Python, ROS)

Tags: python, git, bash, ros

I'm facing quite a head breaking error whenever I want to run my program. My team members are using the same code and are not getting the error. The first time I got the error, I asked a member of my team to commit his code (the exact same as mine) via git and pulled it in. The program runned without error. However, the problem keeps occurring even when I get code via git from my colleagues (which works for them). Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python
import roslib;  roslib.load_manifest('drone7_project')
import rospy
# bunch of other import statements
```

Whenever I run the program, this is the error I'm receiving:

/bin/bash /home/user/Projects/catkin_ws/src/drone7_project/Project/drone_program.py
/home/user/Projects/catkin_ws/src/drone7_project/Project/drone_program.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"drone7_project"'
/home/user/Projects/catkin_ws/src/drone7_project/Project/drone_program.py: line 2:`import roslib;  roslib.load_manifest("drone7_project")'

The drone7_project package exists and shouldn't be the problem. I shouldn't be getting the syntax error since all my other team members aren't getting it (4 members) and we're using the exact same code.

Note the use of single and double quotes the error returns around drone7_project while in the code only single quotes are used. I've tried with double quotes, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing your Python code with a Python interpreter (instead, your shell wants to run that code, which yields the syntax error you are observing). Have you checked what `/usr/bin/env  python` actually returns on your system?

You have to set your PATH properly, so that it contains a directory which contains the executable to the Python interpreter with which you want to run your Python script.

An alternative approach is to explicitly call the Python interpreter of choice, and provide the path to your Python script as an argument, as in

```
$ /path/to/python27 /home/user/Projects/catkin_ws/src/drone7_project/Project/drone_program.py
```